# Convert string to NumPy datetime64 dtype

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, datetime

I program gets a string of current time every minute as `date = '201711081750'`

I want to store these strings as np.datetime64 into an array.

I think I could convert this kind of strings as

```
>>> date = '201711081750'

>>> np.datetime64( date[:4] +'-'+date[4:6]+'-'+date[6:8]+' ' +date[8:10]+':'+date[10:]  , 'm' )
numpy.datetime64('2017-11-08T17:50')
```

But it looks complicated and I think it might engender errors later.

Are there simpler ways to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### `pd.to_datetime`

```
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime(date, format='%Y%m%d%H%M')
Timestamp('2017-11-08 17:50:00')
```

The important bit here is the format string `'%Y%m%d%H%M'`.

---

#### `datetime.datetime` <sub>equivalent in python.</sub>

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

dt.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d%H%M')
datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 8, 17, 50)
```

Comment: This doesn't yield the possibility of using `np.datetime` with base units like days, since Pandas is set up to cast to nanosecond resolution. Does there exist a similarly easy way to parse `np.datetime` objects from string?

Comment: The work-around I found is to use the pd.to_datetime function as suggested by @cs95 and then use strftime function to customize the format extracted. For example, dt.strftime('%Y-%m') to keep only Year, Month.

Comment: @ifly6 You can always use `pd.to_datetime(date).to_numpy()`.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem. Pandas will throw out of bounds exception when parsing date